# Volley batch request and response

Tags: android, android-volley

Is there a way to send and listen for volley batch requests and responses in android?
i want to sync all the offline data once the network is back.
Currently am using a for loop to add the requests to the queue.I get responses individually for each request.
Is there any way for batch request and response listener?

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem then I resolved it by a little stupid way.It's only useful if you have a small number of requests in a batch. Hope it help :)

```
public static void requestData(@NonNull final Context context, final String url, final String cityID, final int typeOfResult, final int batchId) {
    MySingletonWraper.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            // add json object to list json of this batch
            Batch batch = listBatch().get(batchID);
            batch .getListRespones().add(respone);
            // listBatch is a ArrayList of Object Batch which have id, queue url, list results
            urlsQueue = batch .getUrlsQueue();
            if (urlsQueue.isEmpty()) { // I create a queue for control in a batch, check if it's empty - this is last request
                // parse JsonObject for today weather                    
                parseJsonToWeatherObject(typeOfResult);
                return;
            }
            // only request if sure the previous request is successed
            // if have too many reuqests in a batch, just break it if you can
            requestData(context, urlsQueue .poll(), cityID, typeOfResult, batchID);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // write log error
            error.printStackTrace();
            // refresh this batch
            listBatch().refresh();
            // re-request
            fetch(context, cityID, batchID);

        }
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is realistic implementation of a batch listener. Although it is possible to send multiple requests, responses don't arrive at a same time. It might be important to note that in Volley, network pool size is capped at 4 ( I  believe this is defined by the constant `DEFAULT_NETWORK_THREAD_POOL_SIZE` ). You may add many requests to queue but only 4 get processed at a time. And up to now, Volley doesn't have a callback for completed queue which would technically be a close enough implementation of a batch listener.

So you would still need to work on each response individually it seems. Although considering that network process is expensive, I'd work on the server to pre-process whatever data to be sent to the devices, avoiding the need to do multiple requests.